# Octave's default LU factorization function error

Tags: function, error-handling, octave

New to this forum.

I'm trying to run octave's LU decomposition function with complete pivoting as such:

```
[L, U, p, q] = lu(A)
```

for a matrix A I have and I keep getting this error:

> "element number 4 undefined in return list"

Element 4 is the matrix of column permutations Q. What's going on? Why doesn't it show? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If the matrix `A` is full, the `lu` function [does not perform column exchanges in Octave](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Matrix-Factorizations.html#XREFlu) (**emphasis mine**):

> When called with two or three output arguments **and a spare[sic] input matrix**, `lu` does not attempt to perform sparsity preserving column permutations. Called with a fourth output argument, the **sparsity preserving column transformation *Q* is returned**, such that *P* * *A* * *Q* = *L* * *U*.

So [full pivoting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#LU_factorization_with_full_pivoting) is only performed for sparse matrices to maximize sparsity if the fourth output argument is provided for a sparse matrix. The quote above uses "*A*", but per the function signature provided at the top of the linked Octave documentation section, I believe they meant to write "*S*": "`[L, U, P, Q] = lu (S)`".

There does not appear to be a full pivoting option for full matrices by-default.

I'll note that MATLAB has the same behavior for the [fourth output of its `lu`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/lu.html#d117e840045):

> Column permutation ... . Use this output to reduce the fill-in (number of nonzeros) in the factors of a sparse matrix.

Comment: Oh I see! The matrix I used is full so that's the problem. Seems weird though that there isn't a built-in function for that. Anyway thanks a lot for the help